# Passar parametros em funçoes JS

Tags: javascript

Estou a tentar passar como parâmetro `var vetor[j]` para a função ser executada no `onClick`, no entanto, esse valor que passo como parâmetro vem sempre como `undefined`.

Porque de isso acontecer e como resolver a situação?

```
var vetor = [];
for (j = 0; j < info.length; j++) {

    var div_faceta = document.createElement('div');
    div_faceta.className = "divFacetas";
    div_faceta.id = 'faceta' + j + 'sensor' + idsensor;

    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.id = "checkbox" + j;
    checkbox.name = 'checkbox';

    var jsonValues = {check: checkbox, divfaceta: div_faceta.id, info: info[j]};
    vetor.push(jsonValues);
    checkbox.setAttribute("onClick", "createCheckboxValues(\'"+vetor[j]+"\')");


          function createCheckboxValues(json) {
          console.log(json)  - comes as an object
          console.log(json.check) - comes as undefined
          ..................
```

Comment: Devias usar JSON.stringify. Podes colocar o resto do código  para percebermos melhor o que queres fazer? Se estás a construir isso com JS não faz muito sentido usares `checkbox.setAttribute("onClick",`, podias usar diretamente no elemento.

Answer (score 0):

Tente algo do tipo:

```
var vetor = [];
for (j = 0; j < info.length; j++) {

var div_faceta = document.createElement('div');
div_faceta.className = "divFacetas";
div_faceta.id = 'faceta' + j + 'sensor' + idsensor;

var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
checkbox.type = "checkbox";
checkbox.id = "checkbox" + j;
checkbox.name = 'checkbox';

var jsonValues = {check: checkbox, divfaceta: div_faceta.id, info: info[j]};
vetor.push(jsonValues);
//checkbox.setAttribute("onClick","createCheckboxValues(\'"+vetor[j]+"\')");

checkbox.click(function(){
    createCheckboxValues(vetor[j]);
});

      function createCheckboxValues(json) {
      console.log(json)  - comes as an object
      console.log(json.check) - comes as undefined
................................................................................
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você esteja colocando no elemento algo como:

```
<button onclick='minhaFuncao(val)' />
```

A função vai receber sempre o objeto do evento (Event)...

O mais simples a se fazer (na minha opinião) é colocar um atributo customizado no elemento HTML:

```
<button data-valor="meu valor" onclick="minhaFuncao()" />
```

E na função você buscaria isso com:

```
function minhaFuncao(evt) {
    var parametro = evt.target.dataset.valor;
}
```

Referência:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Answer (score 0):

Como você está usando Javascript sem usar nenhuma biblioteca para facilitar a manipulação de elementos e eventos então você deveria no mínimo usar o `addEventListener` para poder capturar o evento click, e você nunca deveria tentar concatenar strings para gerar um código

Então o primeiro passo é mudar isso

```js
//assumindo alguns valores que faltavam apenas para poder testar o script
var info = [0,1,2,3];
var idsensor = 1;

var vetor = [];
for (j = 0; j < info.length; j++) {

    var div_faceta = document.createElement('div');
    div_faceta.className = "divFacetas";
    div_faceta.id = 'faceta' + j + 'sensor' + idsensor;
    //adicionando o elemento ao documento para poder testar
    document.body.appendChild(div_faceta);

    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.id = "checkbox" + j;
    checkbox.name = 'checkbox';
    //novamente, adicionando o elemento ao documento para poder testar
    div_faceta.appendChild(checkbox);

    var jsonValues = {check: checkbox, divfaceta: div_faceta.id, info: info[j]};
    vetor.push(jsonValues);
    
    //aqui é o maior problema, desta forma o click funciona, porém ele ainda não vai conseguir pegar o valor
    checkbox.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
        console.log("valor de j: " + j);
        createCheckboxValues(vetor[j])
    });
}

function createCheckboxValues(json) {
  console.log(json); //aqui ainda vai retornar undefined
  //console.log(json.check)
}
```

Se executar este script você vai ver que o click funciona, porém ele ainda não consegue pegar o valor no vetor, e isso ocorre porque o valor de j sempre retorna 4, sendo que ele deveria ser um valor entre 0 e 3.

O porque disso ocorrer é a forma como o javascript trata as variáveis, como o escopo desta variável é maior do que o do evento que a usa, quando o evento em si acontece o valor dela já mudou, então você precisa de alguma forma para manter o valor atual dele na hora que adiciona o handler do event.

Com ES6 isso é simples, seria o caso de usar o let

```js
//assumindo alguns valores que faltavam apenas para poder testar o script
var info = [0,1,2,3];
var idsensor = 1;

var vetor = [];
for (j = 0; j < info.length; j++) {

    var div_faceta = document.createElement('div');
    div_faceta.className = "divFacetas";
    div_faceta.id = 'faceta' + j + 'sensor' + idsensor;
    //adicionando o elemento ao documento para poder testar
    document.body.appendChild(div_faceta);

    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.id = "checkbox" + j;
    checkbox.name = 'checkbox';
    //novamente, adicionando o elemento ao documento para poder testar
    div_faceta.appendChild(checkbox);

    var jsonValues = {check: checkbox, divfaceta: div_faceta.id, info: info[j]};
    vetor.push(jsonValues);
    
    //var jatual = j; isso não funciona pois var tem escopo da função
    let jatual = j;
    checkbox.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
        console.log("valor de jatual: " + jatual);
        createCheckboxValues(vetor[jatual])
    });
}

function createCheckboxValues(json) {
  console.log(json); //aqui ainda vai retornar undefined
  //console.log(json.check)
}
```

Porém usar ES6 ainda pode não ser possível, pois só os navegadores mais modernos possuem suporte, e mesmo assim parcial ao ES6. Então a alternativa mais viável seria se aproveitar dos closures do javascript

```js
//assumindo alguns valores que faltavam apenas para poder testar o script
var info = [0,1,2,3];
var idsensor = 1;

var vetor = [];
for (j = 0; j < info.length; j++) {

    var div_faceta = document.createElement('div');
    div_faceta.className = "divFacetas";
    div_faceta.id = 'faceta' + j + 'sensor' + idsensor;
    //adicionando o elemento ao documento para poder testar
    document.body.appendChild(div_faceta);

    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.id = "checkbox" + j;
    checkbox.name = 'checkbox';
    //novamente, adicionando o elemento ao documento para poder testar
    div_faceta.appendChild(checkbox);

    var jsonValues = {check: checkbox, divfaceta: div_faceta.id, info: info[j]};
    vetor.push(jsonValues);
    
    (function(j){
        checkbox.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
            console.log("valor de j: " + j);
            createCheckboxValues(vetor[j])
        });
    })(j); //repare que aqui a função já é executada, este (j) é a chamada dela onde o j em si é o parâmetro
}

function createCheckboxValues(json) {
  console.log(json); //aqui ainda vai retornar undefined
  //console.log(json.check)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que seu `vetor[j]` é um array com objeto, e no setAttribute, você está definindo uma string do método. Neste caso, o objeto não foi reconhecido como uma string, você precisa convertê-lo, pois você pretende imprimir o parâmetro no método `createCheckboxValues()` do atributo do checkbox, correto:

```
checkbox.setAttribute("onClick","createCheckboxValues(\'"+JSON.stringify(vetor[j])+"\');
```

E dentro do método, você converte em objeto novamente:

```
function createCheckboxValues(json) {
         var obj = JSON.parse(json);
....
```